# Zend framework 2 not found template

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Is there a way, instead of showing the template 404 page, to have an event, and when it doesn't find an controller, or module, to do an action, like a redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `onBootstrap` method in your `Module.php` you can attach a function to execute when an event occurs, the following attach a function to be executed when an error (exception) is raised:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $application = $e->getApplication();
    $em = $application->getEventManager();
    //handle the dispatch error (exception) 
    $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, array($this, 'errorHandler'));
    //handle the view render error (exception) 
    $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR, array($this, 'errorHandler'));
}
```

and then define the function to handle the error in any way you want, the following is an example:

```
public function handleError(MvcEvent $e)
{
    //get the exception
    $exception = $e->getParam('exception');
    //...handle the exception... maybe log it and redirect to another page, 
    //or send an email that an exception occurred...
}
```

Comment: $exception = $e->getParam('exception'); returns null on a 404 foo.com/daldnadmlamdma;d

Comment: And I also have another question, I also need the flashMessage in there and the redirector, how can I get those?